# Ktor custom feature swap url

Tags: ktor, ktor-client

Im trying to add a custom feature in Ktor. It's basically a url swapper (we have a scenario where domains might be changed during anytime & can't update the client everytime).

We get the swapper list available and need a CustomFeature in Ktor to swap the url based on list. However, the context.request or request.url - everything is val and Im not able to assign new url to the request.

In Retrofit, it used to work like this

```
            if (currentUrl.contains(urlSwapper.oldUrl)) {

                val newUrl = currentUrl.replace(urlSwapper.oldUrl, urlSwapper.newUrl)
                val newHttpUrl = request.url.newBuilder(newUrl)!!.build()

                // build a new request with the new url. replace it

                request = request.newBuilder().url(newHttpUrl).build()
                break
            }
        }
```

In Ktor feature, Im trying something like this

```
            scope.requestPipeline.intercept(HttpRequestPipeline.Transform) {
                val currentUrl =
                    context.url.protocol.name + "://" + context.url.host + context.url.encodedPath

                for (urlSwapper in feature.urlSwappers) {
                    if (currentUrl.contains(urlSwapper.oldUrl)) {
                        val newUrl = currentUrl.replace(urlSwapper.oldUrl, urlSwapper.newUrl)
                        val newHttpUrl = Url(newUrl)
                        context.url(url = newHttpUrl)
                        break
                    }
                }
                proceedWith(subject)
            }
        }
```

Is this the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes, this is the right way. I have a few recommendations:

1. Intercept the `sendPipeline` instead of the `requestPipeline`.

An example:

```
client.sendPipeline.intercept(HttpSendPipeline.State) {
    context.url(url = newUrl)
}
```

2. Get rid of `proceedWith(subject)` call because it's redundant.
3. Try to use `Url` objects instead of strings. You can get the current URL without affecting context by cloning `UrlBuilder` and building `Url` from it: `context.url.clone().build()`